# How to get the back button and session state to work together?

Tags: asp.net, search, session-state, back

There may be an easy answer to this and I just don't see it b/c I am too close to the project - so be it.

I have an asp.net 2.0 search application.  It is a series of pages that start with a search form and end with the results being displayed to the user.  Between the search and results page is a filter page that displays a series of filters the user can filter down the search results to.  I execute the initial search on the search page and store the results in the session.  If the initial search results total more than a certain number (let us say 50 for the sake of the example), the user is taken to the filters page.  There they are presented with a number of filters they can apply to the results.

Once the selected filters have been applied to the search results, if the count is still more than 50 they stay on the page with only the filters they have not selected still displayed on the page.  If the count is less than 50, they are taken to the results page.  Now if they are on the filters page but wish to see the results, there is a button that takes the current state of the results and takes the user to the results page.

**Here is my problem** - if I am on the results page after applying some filters and click on the back button (none of the pages cache), how can i get the previous state of the search results BEFORE whatever filters I selected had been applied?  Even further, if I got to the results page after a series of say 4 "apply filters" (apply filter - still over 50, apply other filter - still over 50, apply yet another filter - still over 50, and finally apply another filter - yay! under 50 go to results page), how do I get each version of the ever shrinking search results from the session if I keep hitting the back button?

Sorry if this is a bit weird and not that easy to understand - this is one of the problems that is not simple enough to just wrap it in a few simple sentences.

I am most eager for any thoughts (pertaining to the question at hand) or questions.

**UPDATE -** 
FYI, I did not decide on the mult-page design.  A requirement stated that it follow the flow of an existing third-party search app (reverse engineering is wonderful right?).

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should keep your search and filtering info on the url rather than in the session state. I have worked for a couple of years on a search application, and I wish I have gone that way first.

Just think about bookmark, if a user bookmark a result page, it would be nice for him if he can get his results back tomorrow, from the bookmark. You can't do that if you store search parameters in the session state.

Comment: I assume this is web forms and you are putting items in the session.  Can you post some code.  Are you able to do some of these refinements in modal popups to avoid going from page to page?

Comment: unfortunately i am unable to post any code for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Not to be too critical, but what you described sounds like a seriously jacked up way of handling search.

Typically, your search criteria and results are on the same page.  When you modify the criteria and click search you should just display the top 50 results and let them know there are more.  This can't be any more expensive an operation that what you've described because you have to run the queries under both circumstances anyway.

Take a look at NewEgg.com and try their "advanced search" from [this page](http://www.newegg.com/Store/SubCategory.aspx?SubCategory=446&name=Motherboard-CPU-VGA-Combo).  You'll notice there are about 20 different criteria factors on the left.  As you add a new criteria, the bread crumb at the top of the page changes.  They have a little (x) next to each in the bread crumb so you can quickly eliminate any criteria from your search results.  Voila no back button needed.

Note that at no point do you need session state to handle this.  At most you could use hidden form fields which would still support back button usage in the browser, if they really wanted to.

Comment: I agree, but the multi-page design was already dictated through requirements.  I really just need suggestions on how to solve the problem at hand (asp.net session state and back button), and not discussions about the flow.

Comment: @DanAppleyard: then just use Hidden Fields instead of session state to store your filter data?  This way state is dictated by the client request, instead of by what the server thinks is next.

Answer (score 0):

Use your current session-based parameters as is, but let any querystring-parameter override them. This way you keep your values w/o assigning them to every url, yet adjusts to any previous manual data-enrty (querystrings in the browser-history).

(And don't use POST for search.)